Putnam 1988 A5 Question
I am looking for a different proof of the exercise asked in the 1988 Putnam exam for question A5. The question asks to show there exists a unique function from the positive real numbers to the positive real numbers, $f(x)$, such that $$f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$$
I have seen a lot of solutions online and all of them use the technique of defining a sequence of functions $a_n$ as $a_0=x$ and $$a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$$ and then either finding an explicit formula for the terms of the sequence or using it to show that $f(x)=2x$. I was wondering whether there was some other way of proving that $2x$ is the only function that satisfies the equation, without using this technique. Maybe some way of proving this using more "standard" olympiad functional equation tricks.
I also wanted to ask, why the sequence trick would be motivated, or why it would seem natural. I didn't find it particularly intuitive as a method to solve this problem, I don't have much experience with functional equations however so I may have just never seen something similar before.

I think looking at iteration paths is natural here...after all, there aren't a whole lot of tools that apply to all functions.  $2x$ jumps out, of course, as it is the only linear example, so it seems sensible to imagine another example and then argue that some sequence of iterations must go negative.

Yeah, the sequence approach looks pretty natural to me.

See this duplicate. It has two different methods given in the answers. Also, other duplicates a linked. And see also this post.

@DietrichBurde  Unless I am misreading, the duplicate only gives the iteration method.  There is another posted solution, which the author themselves describes as "fatally flawed".

Because we don't have continuity or other conditions, the $a_n$ is literally the only values that will give you any information about $f(x_0)$. So apart from it being "natural", it's the only thing that you can do (esp if you assume a nice solution exists). $\quad$ We then apply the condition of positivity (easiest of which is calculating the explicit value of $a_n$, another approach is to look at $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and reach a contradiction) to draw any further conclusions.

There is another solution: $f(x)=-3x$

@gpmath Note that the function is from the positive reals to the positive reals. So yours is not a solution. If we extended the domain and range to all reals, then there are infinitely many solutions.

FWIW If you consider the IMO 1987 question of showing that there are no solutions from the nonnegative integers to itself such that $f(f(n)) = n + 1987$, then this idea of "$a_n$ is literally the only values that will give you any information" only applies, and from a starting value we have an infinite sequence. All solutions essentially studies these chains (some provide more results) to reach a parity argument.

Can I ask why would this iteration argument seem natural? I tried all the olympiad tricks I knew but I've never come across the concept of defining a sequence this way to solve a functional equation, I can't understand how someone would arrive to that without ever having seen a similar solution before.

For $a_0=x$ we define the sequence $a_n$ by $a_{n+1}=f(a_n).$  Then $a_{n+2}=6a_n-a_{n+1}.$ Assume $a_n$ is positive. We are going to show that $a_1=2x,$ i.e. $f(x)=2x.$
Let $h_n={a_{2n+1} \over a_{2n}}.$ Then $h_n>0.$ By applying the recurrence relation to $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$  we get
$$h_{n+1}=g(h_n),\quad g(x)={7x-6\over 6-x}$$ In particular we obtain ${6\over 7}<h_n<6$ for $n\ge 2.$
The function $g(x)$ is increasing on $({6\over 7},6).$ Therefore the sequence $h_n$ is either increasing or decreasing.
Assume ${a_1\over a_0}=h_0<2.$
Then $h_1<h_0$ as the inequlity is equivalent to $h_0^2+h_0-6<0,$ i.e. $(h_0-2)(h_0+3)<0.$ Thus the sequence $h_n$ is decreasing. Let $h=\lim h_n.$ Then $h<2$ and
$$h={7h-6\over 6-h}\quad (*)$$ The only positive solution of the equation is equal $h=2,$ a contradiction.
The same reasoning shows that if $h_0={a_1\over a_0} >2,$ then the sequence $h_n$ is increasing. As $h_n<6$ the sequence $h_n$ is bounded. Its limit satsfies   $h>2.$ The identity $(*)$ implies $h=2,$ a contradiction.

As an aside, you are essentially calculating the explicit value of $a_n = A2^n +B(-3)^n$, just in a different way. (OP mentioned wanting a different way). $\quad$ There are ways to avoid the explicit calculation to arrive at a contradiction (EG We know from the underlying theory that if the ratio of terms isn't exactly 2, then the limit of the ratio is $-3$, so some value will be negative.)

By definition  $6x\gt f(x)$ for all $x$.

@Calvin Lin: You can prove maybe that the restriction of $f(x)$ to positive real is linear so  $f(x)=mx$ and what remains would be to calculate $m=2$

@Piquito I don't think that can be done, at least not simply. Reason being that there isn't much means of relating $f(a+b)$ to $f(a), f(b)$, especially if they are not in the orbits $f^n(a), f^n(b)$. You might be able to work with $f(a + b) > f(a) + f(b)$ for particular values, but you do not have much control over them thereafter. As such, I'd be interested in seeing such an approach.

@Calvin Lin: Perhaps the main problem here is to prove the uniqueness of the solution and not to find $f(x)=2x$ which is very simple (starting by trying to see if there is a polynomial solution we immediately have that $f(x)=ax$ where $a^2+a=6$, that is, there are two solutions $f(x)=2x$ and $f(x)=-3x$ where the solution with $-3$ is ruled out by the positive values ​​imposed by the O.P.). That is why, because of the uniqueness, I asked you to try to prove the necessary linearity of $f$. My respects.

I get what you're wanting to do. However, I've not seen it successfully executed. While that's not to say it can't ever be done, given that this is a famous putnam problem that numerous people have tried, it does imply that a less conventional approach is needed.

@CalvinLin I have modified the answer, so as to avoid explicit calculation of the sequence.

(minor typo) $\frac{ a_1} { a_0} = h_0$, not $h_1$.   $\quad$ (Clarifying that my previous comment as at Piquito, not Ryszard.)

@CalvinLin Thanks. Corrected while watching US Open.
